# Freeze excel column with c#

Tags: c#, excel, freeze

I generate an excel spread-cheat with c# and I want to freeze the first column.
This is the code that I use :

```
    public static void SaveToExcel(object[,] data)
    {
        Excel = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.CreateObject("Excel.Application", String.Empty);
        Excel.ScreenUpdating = false;
        dynamic workbook = Excel.workbooks;
        workbook.Add();

        dynamic worksheet = Excel.ActiveSheet;

        const int left = 1;
        const int top = 1;
        int height = data.GetLength(0);
        int width = data.GetLength(1);
        int bottom = top + height - 1;
        int right = left + width - 1;

        if (height == 0 || width == 0)
            return;

        dynamic rg = worksheet.Range[worksheet.Cells[top, left], worksheet.Cells[bottom, right]];
        rg.Value = data;

        // Set borders
        for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
            rg.Borders[i].LineStyle = 1;

        // Set header view
        dynamic rgHeader = worksheet.Range[worksheet.Cells[top, left], worksheet.Cells[top, right]];
        rgHeader.Font.Bold = true;
        rgHeader.Interior.Color = 189 * (int)Math.Pow(16, 4) + 129 * (int)Math.Pow(16, 2) + 78;
        rg.EntireColumn.AutoFit();

        // Show excel app
        Excel.ScreenUpdating = true;
        Excel.Visible = true;
    }
```

Could You Please Help me???

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The right solution is to add the following code :

```
        worksheet.Activate();
        worksheet.Application.ActiveWindow.SplitColumn = 1;
        worksheet.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set

```
yuorRange.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = true;
```

Have a look at

- [Window.FreezePanes Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208531%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
- [Window.SplitColumn Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb209271%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
- [Window.SplitRow Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb209275%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks for your answer, it didn't solve my problem but it helped me very much